# Why is regex.IsMatch(str) faster than str.EndsWith (invariant culture)?

Tags: .net, regex, string, performance

This is some micro-benchmarking for a code path that is traversed a gazillion times per nanosecond and needs to be fast.

For the code snippet below, comparing

- `x.EndsWith(y, InvariantCulture)`
- `Regex(y, Compiled | CultureInvariant).IsMatch(x)`

I get the following figures:

```
=============================
Regex   : 00:00:01.2235890. Ignore this: 16666666
EndsWith: 00:00:03.2194626. Ignore this: 16666666
=============================
Regex   : 00:00:01.0979105. Ignore this: 16666666
EndsWith: 00:00:03.2346031. Ignore this: 16666666
=============================
Regex   : 00:00:01.0687845. Ignore this: 16666666
EndsWith: 00:00:03.3199213. Ignore this: 16666666
```

In other words, `EndsWith` needs 3 times as much time as `Regex`.

I should note that I experimented with other values and **depending on the string values used, sometimes `EndsWith` is faster, sometimes `Regex` is**.

`EndsWith(x, InvariantCulture)` boils down to some argument checking and then <strike>[`extern int nativeCompareOrdinalEx(String, int, String, int, int)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,97a2816565a71677,references), which I'd expect to be fast</strike>. (As @nhahtdh correctly pointed out, in the case of `InvariantCulture` it calls `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IsSuffix which calls InternalFindNLSStringEx`. I had accidentally followed the `Ordinal` trail)

**N.B.**: I just found out that when calling EndsWith with `Ordinal` instead of `InvariantCulture`, EndsWith gets so much faster than Regex... Unfortunately there's no `RegexOptions.Ordinal` to compare it with.

I also expected the compiled regular expression to be fast, but how can it beat the specialized method?

Le code:

```cs
string[] BunchOfIDs =
{
    "zxc@x@432143214@O@abcße",
    "zxc@x@432143214@T@abcßX",
    "qwe@x@432143214@O@abcße",
    "qwe@x@432143214@XXabc",
    "zxc@x@1234@O@aXcße",
    "qwe@y@1234@O@aYcße",
};

var endsWith = "@abcße";
var endsWithRegex = new Regex("@abcße$", RegexOptions.None);

int reps = 20000000;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("=============================");
    int x = 0;
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int j = 0; j < reps; j++)
    {
        x += BunchOfIDs[j % BunchOfIDs.Length].EndsWith(endsWith, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) ? 1 : 2;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("EndsWith: " + sw.Elapsed + ". Ignore this: " + x);

    x = 0;
    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int j = 0; j < reps; j++)
    {
        x += endsWithRegex.IsMatch(BunchOfIDs[j % BunchOfIDs.Length]) ? 1 : 2;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Regex   : " + sw.Elapsed + ". Ignore this: " + x);
}
```

Comment: `EndsWith(x, InvariantCulture) boils down to some argument checking and then extern int nativeCompareOrdinalEx(String, int, String, int, int), which I'd expect to be fast.` You called EndsWith with InvariantCulture, so shouldn't it call `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IsSuffix` which calls `InternalFindNLSStringEx`? http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,41a31e4feec3ef41

Comment: @nhahtdh You're right. Will double-check this and update.

Comment: When you increase the number of reps by a factor of 10, the difference is much less pronounced (endswith:21secs vs regex:17secs -- much less than the 2-3x speedup when fewer reps are run). Perhaps the JIT does heavier optimizations on hot codepaths (Safari's JS interpreter does this to optimize launch speed). On the other hand, it would make sense for a compiled regex to be heavily optimized from the start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be

Because **`StringComparison.InvariantCulture != RegexOptions.CultureInvariant`**!

This snippet

```
var str = "ss";
var endsWith = "ß";
var endsWithRegex = new Regex("ß$",
    RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
Console.WriteLine(str.EndsWith(endsWith, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
    + " vs "
    + endsWithRegex.IsMatch(str));
```

prints

```
True vs False
```

So it looks like RegexOptions.CultureInvariant does not imply things implied by StringComparison.InvariantCulture. Is RegexOptions.CultureInvariant perhaps more like StringComparison.Ordinal?